# Whenever i use cin and use spaces in the string, why does it just skip through the whole thing?

Tags: c++, cin

I made a program that should take input print it. Then run a simple addition thing but when i use spaces in the input it skips through the addition. I do not know what the problem is.

this is the class stuff

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Cheese {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        void setName(string x){
            cin >> x;
            x = name;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        void print(){
            cout << name << endl;
        }

};
```

this is the main stuff

```
int main()
{
    string h;
    Cheese hole;
    hole.setName(h);
    hole.getName();
    hole.print();
```

this part is getting skipped through without letting me input

```
    int x = 5;
    int y = 16;
    cout << x+y;
    num(x);
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    cout << "Type in a number and press enter.";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Repeat.";
    cin >> b;
    c = a+b;
    cout << c << endl;

    if(c <= 21){
        cout << "Good job!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You fail!";
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Your `setName` function should be called `readStringAndDiscard`.

Comment: That `setName` method does not make sense. Either you want to set the name from the string given as a parameter **or** you want to read from stdin, but not both...

Comment: There are too many errors and misconceptions to be fixed for this code. This question appears to be too broad.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Too broad is the new too localized :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, I tried to start out somewhere, but :P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you divide the responsibilities a little differently.  The `Cheese` class's `setName` function should simply take a string and set the instance's member variable to the given argument.

Then your program can read from standard input and populate a string within `main`, and pass that string to `setName`.

To be more concrete:

```
class Cheese {
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        void setName(const string& x){
           // change this code to set the 'name' member variable
        }
        [...]    
};
```

And the main becomes:

```
int main()
{
    string h;
    Cheese hole;
    std::string input_name;
    cout << "Type a name and press enter.";
    cin >> input_name;  // Will read up to first whitespace character.
    hole.setName(input_name);
    hole.getName();  // this is a no-op: compiler may warn of unused return value
    hole.print();
```

In general, reading standard input as part of a class's interface is a bad idea, because it makes it hard to re-use that class in the future (for example, with programs that take input from a file instead of from a human at a console).

Answer (score 0):

The input that you pass to cin input stream skips any white space, Tab space or newline. If you wish to input string then you can use `cin.getline(string s)`. The input after the white space gets passed to next waiting cin, as the next cin accepts integer and it get a character string it skips that. Thus when enter a string with white spaces the program skips the remaining part.